# raspberry pi 1 model B only pwr led lit up

Tags: raspbian, opencv3.0

i installed Raspbian Jessy operating systems and installed Opencv 3.0.0 on raspberry pi 1 model B.after trying capture an image with Niro Rapi-cam raspberry pi went power off. is that because of Raspberry pi 1 model  B  has not ability to run opencv 3.0.0? now only red light lit up and no screen displays.i tried few times reinstalling Raspbian Jessy and Opnecv 3.0.0 still only red light lit up and nothing on display.

Comment: I do believe that Debian (hence Rasbpian Jessie too) doesn't support the architector of the RPi 1 out of the box. My advice is to reinstall Raspbian Wheezy, check if things boot properly. If so than the problem is in the combination Jessie+RPi 1.

Comment: thanks i'll try install wheezy. and what about Opencv 3.0.0 is it also heavy to run on raspberry pi 1 model B? should i try another old version of Opencv?

Comment: The new version should actually be optimized. However it is still OpenCV and I wouldn't do too much processing on the Pi itself. Usually on such platform you either decrease the image's quality a lot or transfer it to a more powerful machine (via the Ethernet port for example since it's already present) where it can be processed. One of the main issues is that (as far as I know) OpenCV can't use the GPU (if you have a PC with Nvidia for example you can use the CUDA API of OpenCV) so it's CPU-only processing.